# Trying to add an extra column in the data set to calculate daily percentage returns of each asset

Tags: r, date, finance

My data set looks like this:

```
symbol  date    adjusted
BAC 2000-01-03  13.61120
BAC 2000-01-04  12.80331
BAC 2000-01-05  12.94381
BAC 2000-01-06  14.05027
BAC 2000-01-07  13.68145
BAC 2000-01-10  13.20725
```

Under symbol, there are three different stocks. I want to add a column with the daily returns on the asset, but I am stuck on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that daily return is the difference between the previous day and current day, this should give you what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(symbol) %>% 
  mutate(return = adjusted - lag(adjusted, 1))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   symbol [1]
  symbol date       adjusted return
  <chr>  <date>        <dbl>  <dbl>
1 BAC    2000-01-03     13.6 NA    
2 BAC    2000-01-04     12.8 -0.808
3 BAC    2000-01-05     12.9  0.140
4 BAC    2000-01-06     14.1  1.11 
5 BAC    2000-01-07     13.7 -0.369
6 BAC    2000-01-10     13.2 -0.474
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulating data with multiple `symbol` values; then, as Just James' comment suggests, apply the `diff` function to each group separately using `tapply`. You need to add one NA at the start since you can't calculate a return for the very first value.

```
df <- structure(list(symbol = c("BAC", "BAC", "BAC", "BAC", "BAC", 
"BAC", "CAB", "CAB", "CAB", "CAB", "CAB", "CAB", "ACB", "ACB", 
"ACB", "ACB", "ACB", "ACB"), date = c("2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", 
"2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-03", 
"2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-10", 
"2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", 
"2000-01-10"), adjusted = c(13.6112, 12.80331, 12.94381, 14.05027, 
13.68145, 13.20725, 13.6112, 12.80331, 12.94381, 14.05027, 13.68145, 
13.20725, 13.6112, 12.80331, 12.94381, 14.05027, 13.68145, 13.20725
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))

df$returns <- unlist(tapply(df$adjusted, df$symbol, function(adj) c(NA, diff(adj))))
df
   symbol       date adjusted  returns
1     BAC 2000-01-03 13.61120       NA
2     BAC 2000-01-04 12.80331 -0.80789
3     BAC 2000-01-05 12.94381  0.14050
4     BAC 2000-01-06 14.05027  1.10646
5     BAC 2000-01-07 13.68145 -0.36882
6     BAC 2000-01-10 13.20725 -0.47420
7     CAB 2000-01-03 13.61120       NA
8     CAB 2000-01-04 12.80331 -0.80789
9     CAB 2000-01-05 12.94381  0.14050
10    CAB 2000-01-06 14.05027  1.10646
11    CAB 2000-01-07 13.68145 -0.36882
12    CAB 2000-01-10 13.20725 -0.47420
13    ACB 2000-01-03 13.61120       NA
14    ACB 2000-01-04 12.80331 -0.80789
15    ACB 2000-01-05 12.94381  0.14050
16    ACB 2000-01-06 14.05027  1.10646
17    ACB 2000-01-07 13.68145 -0.36882
18    ACB 2000-01-10 13.20725 -0.47420
```